# RewriteRule causes 500 error

Tags: mod-rewrite

Here is my rule:

```
RewriteRule ^forward/?$ forward.php?url=$1 - [NC,L]
```

This is what I would like:

Browser URL: `http://mydomain.com/forward/http://anydomainhere.com`

Rewritten to: `http://mydomain.com/forward.php?url=http://anydomainhere.com`

This will be the last rule evaluated if a match is made. Right now it gives me a 500 error and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Check the logs for why you get a 500 error. Is mod_rewrite loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `RewriteRule` to capture a URL with **`//`** since that is stripped down to a single `/` by Apache. Use `ReeriteCond` with `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable instead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+forward/([^?\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ forward.php?url=%1 [L,NE,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove hyphen from your rewrite rule and it should work:

```
RewriteRule ^forward(/.*)?$ forward.php?url=$1   [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

An error 500 usually means that the server configuration is wrong, in your case the rewrite rules. You can usually look up details in Apache’s error logs about what exactly is happening. In your case, it seems that your rewrite rule is syntactically wrong.

This works for me:

```
RewriteRule ^forward/(.*)$ forward.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```